# Fetching not only the specified elements in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have the following documents:

```json
POST colours/_doc/1
{
  "colour": ["green", "red", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "orange", "dark", "bright", "lilac", "turquoise", "gold", "silver"]
}

POST colours/_doc/2
{
  "colour": ["blue", "yellow"]
}

POST colours/_doc/3
{
  "colour": ["green"]
}
```

I want to fetch only those with IDs 1 and 2 because I don't want the ones with green only. I also want to count the number of occurrences in such scenario, so it would return 2. I managed with this query:

```json
GET colours/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "colour": ["red",
              "blue",
              "yellow",
              "pink",
              "orange",
              "dark",
              "bright",
              "lilac",
              "turquoise",
              "gold",
              "silver"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However, I don't want to specify all of the colours in the `terms` query, because in my use case, the array can contain hundreds of values. Ideally would be sth like:

```json
GET colours/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "not_only": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "colour": ["green"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do the following:

- Find the condition: find the `colour` array with one exact item `green`
- Negate the above condition to get the others

The first condition is like this:

```
"bool": {
    "must": [
        {
            "match": {
                "colour": "green"
            }
        }
    ],
    "filter": {
        "script": {
            "script": "doc['colour.keyword'].length == 1"
        }
    }
}
```

To negate the above condition, simple put it in another `bool` like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "colour": "green"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "filter": {
                            "script": {
                                "script": "doc['colour.keyword'].length == 1"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

It depends on your mapping of `colour`, I use `colour.keyword` because my mapping for colour is text, keyword must be used for script.

```
"properties": {
    "colour": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
            "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is everything but `["green"]`

```
{
    "took": 10,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 2,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 0.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "color",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.0,
                "_source": {
                    "colour": [
                        "green",
                        "red",
                        "blue",
                        "yellow",
                        "pink",
                        "orange",
                        "dark",
                        "bright",
                        "lilac",
                        "turquoise",
                        "gold",
                        "silver"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "color",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.0,
                "_source": {
                    "colour": [
                        "blue",
                        "yellow"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```